# In Sharepoint how to get list advanced settings for Opening Documents in the Browser using REST API

Tags: list, sharepoint

Using REST API i want to access this
Settings >> Advanced Settings >> Opening Documents in the Browser

Can anybody know about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In *SSOM* this feature corresponds to [`SPList.DefaultItemOpen property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.defaultitemopen.aspx?f=255):

> Gets or sets a value that specifies whether to open list items in a
>   client application or in the browser.

In *REST/CSOM* this property is **not** exposed but it could be extracted and determined via *List schema Xml*. For more details about this approach follow  [this post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/11/09/an-alternative-way-of-getting-client-object-properties-using-sharepoint-rest-and-csom-apis/).

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to determine whether to open list items in a client application or in the browser using REST API:

```
function schemaXml2Json(schemaXml)
{ 
    var jsonObject = {};
    var schemaXmlDoc = $.parseXML(schemaXml);
    $(schemaXmlDoc).find('List').each(function() {
      $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attr){
           jsonObject[attr.name] = attr.value;
      });
    });
    return jsonObject;
}    

function getDefaultItemOpen(webUrl,listTitle)
{
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')?$select=schemaXml";
    return $.getJSON(endpointUrl).then(function(data){
             var listProperties = schemaXml2Json(data.SchemaXml);
             var flags = parseInt(listProperties.Flags);
             var defaultItemOpen = (flags & 268435456) != 0 ? "Browser" : "PreferClient";
             return defaultItemOpen;   
           });
}
```

Usage

```
getDefaultItemOpen(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents')
.done(function(value){
    console.log('DefaultItemOpen: ' + value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim , It really helps me a lot. Can you please tell me about this condition. (flags & 268435456) != 0  what is this 268435456 reperesnts?